# ServerTimeoutError with MongoDB Atlas using PyMongo (running setup code)

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm running the starter code from MongoDB trying to connect to a cluster I just setup in MongoDB Atlas. I'm getting a Server Selection Timeout Error.

I haven't been able to find anything in the MongoDB troubleshooting docs about this issue.

```py
client = pymongo.MongoClient(
    "mongodb+srv://USR:PWD@cluster0-eoik8.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = client.admin
pprint(db.command("serverStatus"))
```

I've properly encoded the URL (using an online URL encoding service).

The error is

`pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: connection closed,connection closed,connection closed`

Comment: I have these errors too but its intermittent, I'm using gunicorn + gevent. Issue gets worse as we get mote traffic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it wasn't working was because I hadn't whitelisted my IP address.

Comment: I have whitelisted my IP but I still get this error

Comment: In my case whitelisting did the trick, thanks for your help! :)